# populating an array with values from a row in a table

Tags: php

I have code and I am not sure if it is correct and if the structure is possible. Here is the code:

```
$host="localhost";
$username="sample1";
$password="1234";
$db_name="sampledb";

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

function example1(array1) {
//is this allowed??
  $array1 = array();
  $ctr = 0;
  $ctr1=1;
  $sql="SELECT names FROM tblnamelist";
  $result=mysql_query($sql);
  $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
  $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
  //I also want to populate the array1 with all the values that was retrieved in the query then return it as an array
  if($count!=0) {
    while($ctr1<=$count) {
      $array1[$ctr]=$row[$ctr];
    }
  }
}
```

Basically my question is how can I populate `array1` with the values retrieved from the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to return the array, I quite don't like the reference system as the function's user doesn't really know what the function is doing...

```
function get_results()
{
  $array1 = array();

  $sql="SELECT names FROM tblnamelist";
  $result=mysql_query($sql);

  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
      $array1[] = $row;
  }
  return $array1;
}
$array = get_results();
```

Comment: shouldn't the $array1[] in the $array1 = $row part have a ctr?? like $array1[ctr]=$row['names']; ctr++ ?

Comment: No, `$array1[] = $row` will add $row to the end of the array. It'll grow automagically :).

Answer (score 0):

```
function example1(&$array1) {
  //is this allowed?? -- yes, but you have to do it by reference see & in the definition
  $array1 = array();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create an additional array to retrieve your result ,use this function which returns the associative array:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result){

echo $row['field_name'];
}
```

In you case:

```
  $sql="SELECT names FROM tblnamelist";
  $result=mysql_query($sql);
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo $row['field_name'];

}
```

If there is a single row in your result than there is no need of while loop.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 if ($count!=0)
  {
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
      array_push($array1,$row['names']);
    }
  }
 print_r($array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite your while loop to make it look like this. The code below will get a new `$row` from `$result` until there are no more results left. (You don't need that `$count` variable)

```
$array1 = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $array1[] = $row['names'];  // Insert the value of $row['names'] to the end of the array
}

// return your array, or use Jakub's method.
return $array1;
```

Of course, if all you're doing with the values is print them to the screen, you might as well use Harshal's solution. 
In case you'd want to have the function return an array, your function could be:

```
function getNamesArray() {
    $sql="SELECT names FROM tblnamelist";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    // this is the result array that this function will return
    $array1 = array();

    // loop while there are rows in the mysql result
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // Insert the value of $row['names'] to the end of the array
        $array1[] = $row['names'];  
    }
    return $array1;
}

// test the function:
$test = getNamesArray();
var_dump($test);
```

You should consider using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) though. Have a look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). The use of mysql_ functions is [discouraged](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated).

Answer (score 0):

don't need count as the while will iterate through any values
just assign the row to array1

```
$result=mysql_query($sql); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $array1[]=$row;
}
```

if you are using this several times below, you may want to give a logical index to the array;

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $array1[$row['myUniqueRowID']]=$row;
}
```